# How to get only specific location from Firestore database?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do some tweaks to my Firestore database but for some reasons my query is not working. I have a collection of places. This is my db:

```
places
  - place_id
       - name: Concert Hall
       - image: https://www......
       - capacity: 550
       - location: center
```

And I need to get all places from places node WHERE the capacity is bigger than 500, ordered by position (location).

This is my code:

```
val query = placesRef.whereGreaterThan("capacity", 500).orderBy("location");
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore can only order on a single field. Your query requires that it orders on two fields: first on `capacity` to find the places with the right capacity, then on `location` to return the result in the correct order. This type of query is not possible in Firestore.

From the [Firestore documentation comes this similar, invalid query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data):

> **Invalid**: Range filter and first `orderBy` on different fields
>
> ```
> citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("country")
> ```

Your best option is to let the query filter on `population` and then sort the results on `country` in your code.

For a good explanation on why Firestore doesn't support this type of query, have a look at this [video explaining the Firestore query model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI). Spoiler: it's all about the performance guarantees that Firestore has.

Comment: Woow, this is Frank van Puffelen himself answering to my question, Jeez! I read hundreds of your answers regarding Firebase, you're the best!! Regarding Firestore I understand now thanks to your answer!! Thank you so much!!.

Comment: You're welcome Jane, and welcome as a participating member of Stack Overflow! :-)

Comment: Thanks again for helping me!